# How do I separate teams by division in Tableau Public?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a table with all teams separated by the division each team is in. This is what I have so far.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO2us.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO2us.png)

I tried creating parameters but that wasn't the solution. This is what I want as a final table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/grLIo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grLIo.png)